# Why use nginx to deploy tornado instead of its built-in server?

Tags: nginx, tornado

I found out that we can run the tornado application from just firing something like `python main.py`. But everyone else says to deploy tornado with nginx. What are the benefits? I know it's a bit foolish, but I really am confused.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See the notes on Nginx in the Tornado docs:

http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/stable/guide/running.html

Since one Tornado process can only take advantage of one CPU core (**Edit:** See [updated docs](http://tornado.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/running.html) for a development on this), use Nginx to load-balance multiple Tornado processes to use multiple cores 
Additionally, Nginx is likely a more efficient static file handler than Tornado.

Comment: Thanks Davis, But we use amazon load balance service, so we can use tornado built in server for production deployment right?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Amazon's load balancer. But if you're accomplishing the same goals as Nginx--you're running a Tornado process per core, and avoiding using Tornado to serve static files--then that's fine.

Comment: Load balancer just distribute load to different machine by calculating which server is most close to the requested client. Yes we use CDN for serve static content.

Comment: In that case you may still want to run Nginx on each machine in order to balance load among multiple Tornado processes. A single Tornado process running on a multicore machine is not taking full advantage of the machine's processing power.

Comment: @A.JesseJiryuDavis you can run Tornado on multiple cores without running nginx: 

"Tornado includes a built-in multi-process mode to start several processes at once. This requires a slight alteration to the standard main function"