# How to setup nginx + tornado + flask?

Tags: python, nginx, flask, tornado

These are my fully working tornado and flask files:

Tornado:

```
from flaskk import app
from tornado.wsgi import WSGIContainer
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.web import FallbackHandler, RequestHandler, Application

class MainHandler(RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.write("This message comes from Tornado ^_^")

tr = WSGIContainer(app)

application = Application([
    (r"/tornado", MainHandler),
    (r".*", FallbackHandler, dict(fallback=tr)),
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.listen(5052)
    IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Flask:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class Report(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return 'hello from flask'

api.add_resource(Report, '/report')
```

Now I'm trying to setup nginx in front of tornado.
My nginx config file is:

```
worker_processes 3;

error_log  logs/error.;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    # Enumerate all the Tornado servers here
    upstream frontends {
        server 127.0.0.1:5052;
    }

    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    keepalive_timeout 65;

    sendfile on;


    server {
        listen 5050;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            proxy_pass_header Server;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5050;
        }
    }
}
```

When I do a

> localhost:5050/

then I get the nginx welcome page. But when I do

> localhost:5050/report

then I get a 404. Tornado is running on port 5052.
Why is nginx not calling tornado which thereby should get the result from flask?

Am I missing something here?

Comment: This seems like a bad design. Flask and Tornado serve the exact same purpose.

Comment: You don't need Tornado as a WSGI container. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: @cricket_007 because of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23394080/why-use-nginx-to-deploy-tornado-instead-of-its-built-in-server

Comment: Okay, that said nothing about Flask.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13163990/why-use-tornado-and-flask-together

Comment: also I have been reading many examples online which use flask for api endpoints served behind tornado servers which is behind an nginx load balancer

Comment: I understand that one is blocking and another one, but your routes are not complex enough to warrant using Flask in addition to Tornado. Anyways, does `/tornado` work?

Comment: @cricket_007 the one I posted is merely an example. i havent written all the complex routing I will need to do on my flask endpoints. i am just trying to test the waters of nginx at the moment and will work on the routing later. yes localhost:5052/tornado does work.

Comment: No, don't hit Tornado directly. Use nginx  at `localhost:5050/tornado`.

Comment: ^ That doesn't work. Gives me a 404 :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you don't want to proxy to `localhost:5050` because that is Nginx itself

You want to proxy to `upstream frontends`.

```
proxy_pass http://frontends;
```

---

Regarding your Flask issues, I've gotten this to work fine.

```
@app.route('/report')
def report():
    return 'hello from flask'
```

```
$ curl localhost:5052/report
hello from flask
```

When I added in Flask Restful, that still worked.

---

You said you see the index page of nginx, so it is running, you just need to correctly hook the other ports together.

The `proxy_pass` fix seemed to work for me.

```
$ curl localhost:5050/report
"hello from flask"
$ curl localhost:5050/tornado
This message comes from Tornado ^_^
```

Comment: I updated it to "proxy_pass http://frontends;" but that didn't help. flask and tornado are working individually. the problem is that nginx is not connecting to tornado. i am trying to search online reading many examples but nothing seems to work :(

Comment: I have a full working nginx + tornado app myself. https://github.com/cricket007/docker-tornado-site/blob/master/nginx/config/tornado.conf#L44

Comment: I just ran nginx and `proxy_pass http://frontends;` works fine. `localhost:5050/tornado` and `localhost:5050/report` come back correctly.

Comment: woah! could you please show me your nginx config file? did you make any changes in the config file posted above?

Comment: It is the exact same file as yours but with the `proxy_pass` pointing to `http://frontends;` like I said already

Comment: PHEW! after rebooting my system, its now working for me too! i would always use "nginx -s reload" to restart the nginx. is that not the correct way?

Comment: Thank you so much for sticking with me man! You're totally awesome! :)

Comment: I would put nginx on a `systemctl` service in linux and restart that way, but I guess `-s reload` should work

Comment: And personally, I might use Hug or Falcon if all you want is a separate RESTful API behind Tornado.

Comment: Will definitely check em out. Thanks!